# MongoServerError: Cannot create field 'count' in element

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

When the database matches the below value then I want to increase the count by 1.

```js
const inr = await Postproduct.updateOne({"uid":123456,"userclick.email":"neelshah486@gmail.com"},{$inc: { "userclick.count": 1}})
```

But right now I'm getting the following error while doing so.
[image: Error]

And this is my database

[image: MongoDB Output]

Kindly help me with the same. What I want to do is every time the user clicks the button. I want the count to increase by 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `userclick` is an array, you will need to use an array operator for updating just the one element.

In this case, since the query uniquely identifies one element, you can use the [$](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/crud/write-operations/embedded-arrays/#match-the-first-array-element) positional operator, like:

```
await Postproduct.updateOne(
    {"uid":123456,"userclick.email":"neelshah486@gmail.com"},
    {$inc: { "userclick.$.count": 1}}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set default value of count to zero. like this :

```
userClicks:[{
count:{type:Number,default:0,},
email:String,
satisfy:String,
amount:Number,
          }]
```